# Streaming voice between server and client in android

Tags: android, sockets

I'm developing a voice chat between two android devices. Client side works very well but server side is crashing.

I've changed sample rate array size but it's still crashing. As soon as client connects to server, the server crashes.

**client :**

```
package com.example.client;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) @SuppressLint("NewApi") public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private EditText target,target_port;
private TextView streamingLabel;
private Button startButton,stopButton;

public byte[] buffer;
public static DatagramSocket socket;
private int port=50005;        
AudioRecord recorder;

//AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

private int sampleRate =8000;//Integer.parseInt(audioManager.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE));
private int channelConfig = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;    
private int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;       

private boolean status = true;



@SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }


    target = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.target_IP);
    streamingLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.streaming_label);
    startButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.start_button);
    stopButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.stop_button);
    target_port=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.target_Port);
    streamingLabel.setText("Press Start! to begin");

    startButton.setOnClickListener (startListener);
    stopButton.setOnClickListener (stopListener);
    target.setText("192.168.1.100");
    target_port.setText("50005");

   // AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
  //  String rate = audioManager.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE);
  //  String size = audioManager.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_FRAMES_PER_BUFFER);
  //  Log.d("Buffer Size and sample rate", "Size :" + size + " & Rate: " + rate);
}

private final OnClickListener stopListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                status = false;
                recorder.release();
                Log.d("VS","Recorder released");
    }

};

private final OnClickListener startListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                status = true;
                startStreaming();           
    }

};

public void startStreaming() {


    Thread streamThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {


                int minBufSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);
                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
                Log.d("VS", "Socket Created");

                byte[] buffer = new byte[512];

                Log.d("VS","Buffer created of size " + minBufSize);
                DatagramPacket packet;

                final InetAddress destination = InetAddress.getByName(target.getText().toString());
                Log.d("VS", "Address retrieved");

                if (minBufSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,minBufSize);
                Log.d("VS", "Recorder initialized");
                if (recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED)
                    recorder.startRecording();}


                while(status == true) {


                    //reading data from MIC into buffer
                    minBufSize = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                    //encoding to base64
                 // String buffer1= Base64.encodeToString(buffer, Base64.DEFAULT);

                    //putting buffer in the packet
                    port=Integer.parseInt(target_port.getText().toString());
                    packet = new DatagramPacket (buffer,buffer.length,destination,port);
                    System.out.print(buffer);
                    Log.d("", "BUFERRRR");
                    socket.send(packet);


                }

            } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("IOException message:",e.getMessage().toString());


            } 


        }

    });
    streamThread.start();
 }
 }
```

**Server :**

```
package com.example.server;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) @SuppressLint("NewApi") public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private Button receiveButton,stopButton;
private TextView recive;
private EditText port;
public static DatagramSocket socket;
private AudioTrack speaker;
private int port_num=50005;



private int sampleRate =44100;//Integer.parseInt(audioManager.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE));   
private int channelConfig =  AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO;    
private int audioFormat = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;       
int minBufSize =AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, channelConfig, audioFormat);
byte[] buffer;  //256

private boolean status = true;



@SuppressLint("NewApi") @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }


    receiveButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.receive_button);
    stopButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.stop_button);
    recive= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.receive_label);
    receiveButton.setOnClickListener(receiveListener);
    stopButton.setOnClickListener(stopListener);
    port=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

   //AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
  //  sampleRate =Integer.parseInt( audioManager.getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE));
}


private final OnClickListener stopListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        status = false;

        speaker.release();
        Log.d("VR","Speaker released");

    }

};


private final OnClickListener receiveListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        status = true;


        startReceiving();

    }

};

public void startReceiving() {

    Thread receiveThread = new Thread (new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {



                       buffer= new byte[1024];
                        DatagramSocket socket = null;

                        try {
                            socket = new DatagramSocket(50005);
                            Log.d("VR", "Socket Created");

                            if (minBufSize != AudioRecord.ERROR_BAD_VALUE) {
                            speaker = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,sampleRate,channelConfig,audioFormat,1024,AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
                            if (speaker.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED)
                            speaker.play();}
                            while(status == true) {

                                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);

                                socket.receive(packet);
                                Log.d("VR", "Packet Received");


                                buffer=packet.getData();
                                Log.d("VR", "Packet data read into buffer");

                               buffer= Base64.decode(buffer, Base64.DEFAULT);
                                speaker.write(buffer, 0, minBufSize);
                                Log.d("VR", "Writing buffer content to speaker");
                        }

                        } catch (SocketException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }




                }

    });
    receiveThread.start();
}}
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is buffer size and the while loop